# How to load the jQuery provided by WordPress in the footer?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Setting the `$in_footer` parameter to `true` in [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) loads a script in the footer. This is great if I'm adding a new script. However, WordPress already provides a version of jQuery by default and this is enqueued in the document head.

How can I move the jQuery provided by WordPress from the header to the footer?

Comment: This might help you out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Hi @ahmad-albayati, I already linked to that article in the Codex. Please see my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to de-register the existing query and re-register it to load in the footer.

```
function jquery_in_footer() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');

        // load the local copy of jQuery in the footer
        wp_register_script('jquery', home_url(trailingslashit(WPINC) . 'js/jquery/jquery.js'), false, null, true);


        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'jquery_in_footer');
```

Bear in mind that if you have any other scripts enqueued that depend on jQuery and are not loaded in the footer, WordPress will still load jQuery in the header to satisfy that dependency.

(adapted from http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/)

Edit: If you really want to get crazy, you could modify the WP_Scripts object directly, but then you're dependent on the implementation never changing. I imagine that would change before they even thought of moving jquery.js' location in wp-includes :)

But just for fun…

```
function load_jquery_footer() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->in_footer[] = 'jquery';
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'load_jquery_footer');
```

Comment: I thought about de-registering and then re-registering. The problem with that approach is the version you re-register won't be the same as the version used by WP in future releases. I was hoping for a filter was available which lets you retain the version of jQuery used but lets you change the $in_footer parameter to true? The link you added and the info about dependent scripts is invaluable! Thank you!

Comment: That's where `home_url(trailingslashit(WPINC) . 'js/jquery/jquery.js')` comes in. It loads the version in wp-includes.

Comment: Cool, I didn't see the WPINC constant. Thanks again!

Comment: One thing I did notice - shouldn't you be using array() as the third param in wp_register_script instead of false?

Comment: In WordPress 4.6.1, jquery depends on jquery-core and jquery-migrate.  So I had to modify the function just a bit removed the dereg for jquery and added:  `wp_deregister_script('jquery-core')` & `wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate')`, then I re-registered jquery-core `wp_register_script('jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', false, null, true)` and jquery-migrate `wp_register_script('jquery-migrate', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js', false, null, true)`. When you enqueue jquery, it will load jquery-core & jquery-migrate into the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `defer` attribute will help. There is a good [article](https://matthewhorne.me/defer-async-wordpress-scripts/) on this topic.
I use the following code for convinient nonblocking loading of any scripts, not just jQuery.

```
// Defer scripts.
function dt_add_defer_attribute( $tag, $handle ) {
    $handles = array(
        'jquery-core',
        'jquery-migrate',
        'fancybox',
    );
    foreach( $handles as $defer_script) {
        if ( $defer_script === $handle ) {
            return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $tag ); // Or ' async src'
        }
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'dt_add_defer_attribute', 10, 2 );
```